# Ant Build issue : Additonal folder getting created

Tags: ant, compilation

need your help at the earliest and I have been breaking my head over this for a while.

Below is my Ant Script.

```
     <property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
     <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>
     <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/allocator"/>
     <property name="classes.dir" value="${basedir}/classes"/>
     <property name="jar.dir"     value="${basedir}/jar"/>
     <property name="main-class"  value="allocator.Allocator"/>
        <path id="classpath_ref">
        <pathelement path="${basedir}/"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
             </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${classes.dir}" /> 
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" /> 
        <delete dir="${jar.dir}" /> 
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
         <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath_ref" includeantruntime="false">
            <src path="${basedir}/supportlibraries"/>
            <src path="${basedir}/com/xyz/framework"/>
            </javac>
        <copy todir="${build.dir}"><fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="jar">

                <java classname="${main-class}" fork="true" >
                     <arg line="username"/>
                     <arg line="password"/>
                  <classpath>
                    <path refid="classpath_ref"/>
                    <pathelement location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
                  </classpath>
                 </java>
            </target>
    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

when i try to run the ant build from eclipse it is creating an additional folder allocator, supportlibraries and com/xyz/framework inside the class folder. why is it creating additional folder? because of the additional folders when the run target executes its not able to locate the allocator class. Please let me know if i am missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<copy>` from the `"compile"` `<target>`.

The `<jar>` in the `"jar"` target should be:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

In the above snippet, `basedir` is `${classes.dir}` instead of `${build.dir}`.

I don't see a need for `build.dir` in your script. All references to it can likely be removed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ${build.dir} error and have changed it now. but still it is creating all three folders inside classes. is it an expected result?

Comment: Yes, that's the expected result. `<javac>` creates those directories.